# How to architect and develop an E-learning, course selling platform like Wes Bos?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nginx, database-design

**Bio** 
I've been working as a front-end developer for the past 6 years. I recently started doing backend work about 6 months ago, and I'm loving it.

**Note:** This is my first time ever asking a question on Stackoverflow. I apologize in advance if I am doing something stupid.

**Main** 
I want to learn how to build a multi-course selling node web app like Wes Bos (http://www.wesbos.com) or like Teachable platform(www.teachable.com) for one author. (For learning and also potentially making and selling my own front end courses in the future since I also have a teaching background)

I have been trying to find a resource to learn to build something like this for a while but haven't been able to find one yet.

**Wes** (Full-stack developer)

He has a few courses: 
1. [www.reactforbeginners.com](http://reactforbeginners.com) 
2. [www.learnnode.com](http://learnnode.com) 
3. [www.flexbox.io](http://flexbox.io) 
etc...

And all of his courses seem to share a single database in mongo. Here is how it works.

1. User visits one of his courses' website. (let's say reactforbeginners)
2. If it's a paid course, then you can buy the course through a credit card (stripe) or Paypal, and you get a link to your email to access your account. When you click on that link, you're directed to a page with a registration form where the email is pre-filled and non-editable, and you can fill out the password and confirmation password input fields to actually sign up for the course.
3. If it's a free course, he collects your email address instead of charging you, and you get a link in your email to actually sign up for the course and the same process as step 2 follows.

And once you're signed up, you can enroll in any of his courses with the same account.

Now, he has a video on the stack he uses on youtube. 
Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CS436KZ35A

I kind of understand everything in the video, however, the part I am stuck at his how to architect the database models and connect everything together. How do I make the students able to buy and enroll all the courses with one account?

I have looked at a lot of ER diagrams and model designs and the best one I could find was this:

[Models Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHB9K.png) <<< Image

I don't think I need the Subjects and Student_Tests_Taken tables, but since I am the only author, do I need an author's table or should I have one for scalibility?
Since I will be handling payments, would I need a table for that? If so, how would it look like?

Should I forget about having multiple courses and make one course work first? 
Are there any Javascript libraries that make this process easier? Any tutorials out there? Any help is appreciated?